# IOS - Touch ID Authentication takes more time after loading

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made one demo for login application with touch id authentication.
It is going fine with touch id authentication but,

## My Problem is

When I do authentication with my touch id it gives me immediate response according the finger scans , But after messaging it took so much time for further process like move forward or display result which I have placed on success.
I have also used Switch Case Statements in my code.

## Code is

```
- (IBAction)touchidRegistration:(id)sender {
    LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    NSError *authError = nil;
    NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"Authenticate using your finger";
    if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
        self.myHud.hidden = NO;
        [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                  localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                            reply:^(BOOL succes, NSError *error) {

                                if (succes) {

                                    self.btnRegister.enabled = YES;
                                  //  self.myHud.hidden = YES;
                                    self.registrationFlag = @"YES";
                                    self.flag = @"";
                                    self.verifiedImage.hidden = NO;
                                    NSLog(@"flag Value is %@",self.flag);
                                    NSLog(@"Done!!!");

                                    [self showMessage:@"Authentication is successful" withTitle:@"Success"];

                                    NSLog(@"User authenticated");

                                } else {

                                    switch (error.code) {
                                        case LAErrorAuthenticationFailed:
                                            self.myHud.hidden = YES;
                                            [self showMessage:@"Authentication is failed" withTitle:@"Error"];
                                            NSLog(@"Authentication Failed");
                                            break;

                                        case LAErrorUserCancel:
                                            self.myHud.hidden = YES;
                                            [self showMessage:@"You clicked on Cancel" withTitle:@"Error"];
                                            NSLog(@"User pressed Cancel button");
                                            break;

                                        case LAErrorUserFallback:
                                            self.myHud.hidden = YES;
                                            [self showMessage:@"You clicked on \"Enter Password\"" withTitle:@"Error"];
                                            NSLog(@"User pressed \"Enter Password\"");
                                            break;

                                        default:
                                            self.myHud.hidden = YES;
                                            [self showMessage:@"Touch ID is not configured" withTitle:@"Error"];
                                            NSLog(@"Touch ID is not configured");
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    NSLog(@"Authentication Fails");
                                }
                            }];
    } else {
        self.myHud.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"Can not evaluate Touch ID");
        [self showMessage:@"Can not evaluate TouchID" withTitle:@"Error"];

    }
}
```

Please help me guys or suggest me any **link** I do not able to search this type of problem on here.I have seen one but its for Swift,I need for **OBJECTIVE - C** 
link:- [swift - touchID takes long time to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967538/swift-touchid-takes-long-time-to-load)

Note:-I am using I-Phone 6 device for testing. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post `showMessage` method ? what are you doing there in `showMessage` ?

Comment: @CodeChanger:-Sorry its confidential i cant post here ,its just simple log message, But its loading on device around 1 min. then and then gives feedback.thanks

Comment: Means you are printing some value with NSLog or ?

Comment: Ya ,whatever operation done on on my device ,I print those data on log.               For Example:-If touch id authentication done it should be move on my home page of Application with containing data from the web services.

Comment: Yes thats what i want your services calling on main thread or in background ?

Comment: My network is good because data are printed immediately when success happen ,But Moving application home page is happen after half of minute.totally confuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer ,
Its Working Fine For me thank you

```
if (succes) {

                                    NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
                                    [myQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

                                        // Background work

                                        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                                            // Main thread work (UI usually)
                                            NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [StaticClass getTouchIdData:@"userInfo"];
                                            if(!([userInfo count] == 0))
                                            {
                                                self.myHud.hidden = YES;
                                                self.flag = @"";
                                                TestViewController *testView = [[TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
                                                [testView setUserInfo:userInfo];
                                                [self.navigationController pushViewController:testView animated:YES];
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                self.myHud.hidden = YES;
                                                self.flag = @"YES";
                                                self.registrationFlag = @"";
                                                [self showMessage:@"For The First time user ,You have to login manually" withTitle:@"Error"];
                                                self.touchIdLoginView.hidden = YES;
                                            }
                                            NSLog(@"User Id is %@",userInfo);
                                            NSLog(@"Done!!!");
                                            NSLog(@"User authenticated");

                                        }];
                                    }];
```